# How to calculate NPER in PHP

Tags: php, math

I can't figure out how to calculate NPER in php.

I did not find any article in google.

I'm very weak in math becouse of it i'm asking for help.

This is what i did so far :(

```
public function Nper($interest, $payment, $loan){
       $nperC = Log10($payment/($payment+$loan+$interest))/Log10(1+$interest);
       return $nperC;
}
if(isset($_POST['NperSubmit'])){
        $calc = new CalculatorModel();
        $months = $calc->Nper($_POST['interest'], $_POST['payment'], $_POST['loan']);
        echo round($months,2);
}
```

Working code (From Tijo John answer)

```
public function Nper($interest, $payment, $loan){
        $interest = $interest / 1200;
        $nperC = Log10 ($payment/ ($payment- $loan * $interest)) / Log10(1 + $interest);

        return $nperC;
    }
    $calc = new CalculatorModel();
    $months = $calc->Nper($_POST['interest'], $_POST['payment'], $_POST['loan']);
    echo round($months,2);
```

Thanks :))

Comment: Use [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) library

Comment: Grzegorz thank you for your help :) I successfully implemented this library without errors, but how to use this for NPER.
in excel we use =NPER(D5/12,-D7,D4) but in php?

Comment: My bad, i was thinking that you are trying to generate a Excel file with formulas in it

Comment: No problem :)) thanks anyway :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should have change the formula as follows

Log10 ($payment/ ($payment- $loan * $interest)) / Log10(1 + $interest)

Comment: convert the value to int and float using `(int)$payment` and `(float) `

Comment: $int = (int)$nperC; $float = (float)$int; return $float;
returns : -2147483648

Comment: ok this formula is true, i forgot to do $interest = $interest / 1200;
now it's working. thank you  very much... :)))

Comment: @Lasha your welcome if the anaswer is useful vote for that

Comment: This does return NAN if $payment < ($loan * $interest), but that means you're paying less than the monthly finance charge, so the loan will never be paid off. (I added a guard clause to return `INF` in this case.)